# jQuery .height() wrong in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a problem reading out the correct height of a `DIV` with jQuery in Safari. I am using `jQuery("#x").height()` to read out the height of the element. In the real situation, I use the result later on in the page. It works well in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but not in Safari.

Here is some code that I have extracted from my page that demonstrates the problem:

The CSS:

```
#x {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  right: 54%;
  width: 40vw;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 10px 3.1vw 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  }
.y {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 330px;
}
.y img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

(some parameters seem superfluous or strange, but I need them in my context and it doesn't change the problem if I leave them out)

HTML:

```
<div id="x">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <div class="y">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/330" alt="my image">
  </div>
  <p class="z"><span>Some text</span><br>Some more text...</p>
</div>
```

Now, with this jQuery code I am getting different results depending on the browser:

```
console.log(jQuery("#x").height());
```

I put all this into a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyELJV?editors=1111

If you load it in Firefox, the console output is 469. If you load it in Safari, it's 154. (addition: in both Chrome/MacOS and in IE11/Win7 the value is 466). Some small part of the difference is due to different default styles, but the main problem is that Safari doesn't take the image into account when getting the height.

If tried different things (that didn't solve the problem):

- I tried `innerHeight()`, `outerHeight()` and `outerHeight(true)` instead of `height()` - no basic difference (slightly different values, but still the problem in Safari).
- I added `width=330 heigth=330` as attributes to the `img` tag, it works in the codepen, but not in my real situation (with another image). Apart from that, the whole thing is responsive, so I'd like to omit these attributes anyway.

By the way: The original images are all 330x330px (i.e. all have aspect ratio 1:1), but they are scaled down on smaller screens.

I'd be very grateful for a solution...

Comment: Try outerHeight(true) That actually MIGHT help.

Comment: I have also tried that already - didn't help...

Comment: Could you write the values that get logged by Jquery in all the browsers?

Comment: I opened the page in all these browsers - is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I meant if you could write the values of the console log here so we might have some data available.

Comment: @Elvanos I added the values to my question: 466 both in Chrome (MacOS) and IE11 (Win7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your css so that safari doesn't change height of image.

```
#x {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  right: 54%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  /* max-width: 330px; */
  padding: 10px 43px 16px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.y {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 330px;
}
.y img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Also use `load` function to fetch exact height of `#x`.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   console.log($("#x").height());  
});
```

You can refer the changed code [here](http://codepen.io/Bhumika107/pen/MyOPMq?editors=1111).

Comment: I have checked this in chrome, firefox and safari on windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer - it solved my problem! In fact, the `load`function alone already was sufficient, I didn't need to change any of the `height` settings. I can only award the bounty 10 hours from now, so I have to wait, but I'll do it.

Comment: @Developer107 Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314988/why-is-the-value-of-height-in-chrome-different-with-safari

Answer (score 1):

I fought a lot with this issue. Safari have a lot of troubles getting the height of an element but I found a javascript method that return the correct height of a specific element.

Here I give you the link and the support confirmation. Actually I used that in a project where I was needing to control an animation depending of an element height.

I hope that it could help someone in my same situation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Use the getBoundingClientRect and access to the height attribute like this:

element.getBoundingClientRect().height

Comment: you could improve your answer with formatting, especially the code.