# jquery outerHeight() gives random values in Safari Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the height of the highest div using outerHeight() jquery function.

Here is my js code:

```
$( window ).load(function(e){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var div = $('.inner_service_block');
    div.each(function(){
        if ($(this).outerHeight(true) > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true); }
    });

    console.log(maxHeight);
});
```

This code works fine in every browser except in Safari (Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4)).

For example the actual div's height is 293px (I can see that in web inspector), while in console I get 250px. But sometimes, after refreshing the page, I get the right value i.e. 293px and after further refreshing I see 250px again.

I've cleared cache, restarted mac, tried in private browsing mode and tried height() function but get the same result.

Here is the workaround that I've found:

```
$( window ).load(function(e){
    setTimeout( function(){
        var maxHeight = 0;
        var div = $('.inner_service_block');
        div.each(function(){
            if ($(this).outerHeight(true) > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true); }
    });

        console.log(maxHeight);

    }, 90);
});
```

I really would like to know what the real problem is here because using setTimeout function is not what I would like to use in this case.

Comment: Have you tried changing `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @Justinas It should then be worst

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago (http://stackoverflow.com/q/36386738/5641669) and also solved it using `$( window ).load(function()...`

Comment: Some async code renders these specific DIVs content making it unrelevant i guess. Maybe other browser are faster to render it or using any cached version

Comment: @Justinas yeah, I've tried that too :(

Comment: @A.Wolff In my js file is no other js code than above. I'm using materializecss and in begin I thought also that there might be some code interference from framework's library, so I've deleted it from project but got the same result.

Comment: @rvaliev And if for testing purpose, you don't include margin, using `outerHeight(/*false*/)`, have you got constant result? And what about `innerHeight()/height()`? It could be an issue regarding CSS file (still) not loaded or specific rule not applied

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah the same result: 293px and 250px – it differs from time to time

Comment: it looks like that there's no difference for Safari between innerHeight(), outerHeight() and outerHeight(true) at all

Comment: And still
for test, what
if you force a redraw: `div.hide().show(0, function() {
  if ($(this).outerHeight(true) > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
  }
}).promise().done(function() {
  console.log(maxHeight);
});`

Comment: @A.Wolff nothing changed. But I've found interesting thing: if I refresh page using keys (cmd+R) then results are wrong, however if I reload page by firstly click in address bar, and then enter, I've got always the right result.

Comment: So ya, seems a cache issue. Is/are this/these div(s) contain(s) image(s)?

Comment: @A.Wolff those divs don't contain images but font icons from google material icons set, and little bit of text.