# jQuery height function returns different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a website for my company, and I decide to use Bootstrap and jQuery to make it go faster. I went to show my website to a co-worker and it didn't look the same as on my computer. After digging further I found the jQuery `height` method was the culprit.

Using the JavaScript console I found on his computer...

```
$('header').height() == 277.552
$('header').outerHeight() == 397.552
$('header').length == 1
```

...and on my computer...

```
$('header').height() == 158
$('header').outerHeight() == 278
$('header').length == 1
```

The part that stumps me is that we both are using Windows 7 and Chrome 69.0.3497.100. Does anyone have a clue as to why this may be happening, or a better way to dynamically find the height of an element? I believe it is irrelevant, but here is my code I am using.

```
$('.sidenav').css('padding-top', Math.max($('header').outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop(), 50) + 30);
```

Comment: if the element is always visible try using Javascript document.querySelector("header").clientHeight; and see if you get the same result

Comment: @Stakvino that returns the same value on both computers. :)

Comment: I had a similar problem a long time ago and got an answer that solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36386738/5641669

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some css elements that are dependent on the user screen height/width.

For example, you could be using a font-size attribute with units like vmin/vw/vh.

Comment: Well, there are pages in which the header has two lines, and then there are pages that 10 lines. Mostly it is the same with 2 exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .height() function returns the height of an element in pixels, so if your code is set up using Bootstrap with predefined templates and sizes in responsive design, you would expect heights and widths to be in percentages values of the screen size, rather than absolute.

Therefore, the $("#someid").height() of a Bootstrap button (for example) would give you two different values on two monitors that differ in their screen resolution.

For Bootstrap websites and systems, adjusting height directly is generally unnecessary and something you want to avoid, as you should use the provided grid and class based system. Instead alter the margins/borders using the margin and padding classes "m" and "p" respectively.

[Bootstrap 4 Spacing Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/)

**Where property is one of:**

```
m - for classes that set margin
p - for classes that set padding
```

**Where sides is one of:**

```
t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom

blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
Where size is one of:

0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
```

Then utilise grids and rows along with responsive utility classes to ensure your website looks similar on different screen sizes, or can adjust accordingly/responsively.

[Bootstrap Grid Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

[Bootstrap Display/Responsiveness Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/)